# $M$ finitely generated $\nRightarrow$ $N$ and $M/N$ finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian, finitely-generated

In an algebra lecture we looked at the following lemma:

> Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ an $R$-module and $N \subset M$ a submodule. Then
>
> $N$ and $M/N$ are finitely generated $\implies$ $M$ is also finitely generated.

I understand the proof for this lemma and it makes sense to me.

Our professor also mentioned the converse:

> $M$ finitely generated $\implies$ $M/N$ finitely generated

> $M$ finitely generated + $R$ noetherian $\implies$ $N$ and $M/N$ finitely generated

Here I don't understand why we don't have:

$M$ finitely generated $\implies$ $N$ and $M/N$ finitely generated

Since $N$ is a submodule of $M$ and therefore $(N,+)$ is a subgroup of $(M,+)$, I would have intuitively said that $N$ also must be finitely generated. But this must be false since we need the condition that $R$ is noetherian for that to be the case.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Think for example of the ring of polynomials in infinite variables $R = K[X_1,X_2,...]$ then $R$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and a submodule nothing else than an ideal. What is a not finitely generated ideal?

Comment: I would say every ideal $I=(a_1,a_2, \dots)$ for $a_i \in R^{\text{ind}}$.

Comment: The group $(M,+)$ of a finitely generated module doesn't have to be finitely generated as a group, only $M$ as module.

Comment: $R^{\text{ind}}$ is the set of all indecomposable elements in $R$.

Comment: indecomposable means irreducible

Comment: No. Then $I = (X_1,X_1 + 1,...) = R$, which is finitely generated. Take better an ideal like $(X_1,X_2,X_3,...)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133728/discussion-between-yanick-and-psl2z).